# Creating variable of typedefd type in SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig, typedef

I have a project with SWIG set up generating python code. I have a `typedef` of `std::string` to `Message` and a `say(Message)` function. I am able to call `say` with a string in python. I want to be able to make a variable of the type `Message` and the `Message` type is exported to the library, but not the python wrapper. Here are my files:

## test.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::string Message
void say(Message s);
```

## test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

void say(Message s)
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

## test.i

```
%module test
%{
#include "test.h"
%}

typedef std::string Message;
%include "std_string.i"
%include "test.h"
```

## Python example

```
import test
test.say('a')
# >>> a

# What I want to be able to do
msg = test.Message('a')
# >>> Traceback (most recent call last):
# >>>  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# >>> AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'Message'
```

My actual use case also involves typedefs to other types (primarily enums) and I'm curious if those cases take any different handling. I believe I could wrap the objects in a class for the SWIG bindings and then modify the SWIG-generated classes (or maybe use a SWIG typemap), but I feel that that's a bit of a roundabout solution to what I would think is a common situation.

I thought this may be an issue with having access to the code in the `string` header, but I run into the same issue if I try to typedef something like an `int`.

My best approach so far has to been a wrapper template:

```
template<typename T>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(T x) : data(x){};
    T data;
    T operator()() { return data; };
};
```

And a corresponding `%template` directive in **test.i**:

```
%template(Message) Wrapper<std::string>;
```

Unfortunately, this seems to have a few drawbacks so far:

- You have to actually call `operator()`, ie, `test.Message('a')()` needs to be called
- You need to either use some conditional compilation or name the wrapper something different from the typedef; otherwise, `test.say` won't accept the wrapper or a string and thus it is not able to be used at all.
- It doesn't seem to work with enums with an error on construction.

I also thought that I may be clever and change `operator*` to just return what was being wrapped, but it looks like SWIG wrapped what was returned anyway.

Comment: I would recommend you to use `const char*`, since `std::string` is not a `POC` type and the memory is allocated on the heap, which operates differently whether it is debug or release. I anticipate that by including `%include "std_string.i"` you get the possibility for creating a `std::string` instance. Have you tried using this as argument?

Comment: My anticipation was wrong, but I still recommend you to use POC types on your interface.

Comment: I would expect to be able to instantiate a string from either `%include std_string.i` or %import std_string.i` as `std_string.i` templates `string` as `basic_string<char>`. Strangely enough, none of those seem to import an object that I can create an instance of. Maybe it's because SWIG seems to handle strings by mapping them to target language strings?

Comment: @JensMunk did you mean POD instead of POC?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Like your comment on weak typedefs

Answer (score 0):

In general in SWIG typedefs should "just work". (There's one exception where I know they regularly don't behave as expected and that's when instantiating templates, but this isn't an issue here.)

In your example I think  that your problem is simply the visibility of the typedef relative to the definition of `std::string`. If you change your .i file to be:

```
%module test
%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "std_string.i"
typedef std::string Message;
%include "test.h"
```

Or

```
%module test
%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "std_string.i"
%include "test.h"
```

Then I'd expect your  example code to work.

In terms of `std::string` vs `const char*` there should be very little observable behavior difference for Python users. Python's native string type will get converted correctly and automatically for either, so the rule I'd stick to is that if you're using C++ then use the C++ type unless there's an overriding reason not to. POD-ness (or lack thereof) is not likely to be the expensive part of your interface and even less likely to be the bottleneck in your performance.

Comment: This seems to give me the same result. The typedefs seem to work when I have access to the object that the typedef aliases. In the case of a string, I'm able to pass a string to the code and have it work but not able to instantiate the alias type. Perhaps a string was a bad example since it is available in most places. Consider `class C {...}; typedef C CAlias;` If I have the `C` declaration in my interface, I can instantiate an object of class `C` and pass it, but SWIG isn't allowing me to instantiate a class `CAlias` and call it that. Is this the expected behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: That's expected behaviour - typedefs are 'weak' in C and C++, so this (mostly) mirrors the behaviour on that side of the language. If you really wanted you could use `%pythoncode %{ CAlias = C %}` to make `CAlias` be a Python type, but it doesn't gain much. If you want `CAlias` to become a strongly typed Python thing in its own right you'll want to use something like `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`, and I can expand to talk about wrapping that. I suspect that possibly all you actually want is SWIG's `%rename` directive to rename the underlying type if the aim of the typedef is just to friendly names.

Comment: The `%pythoncode` way works quite nicely, but isn't really portable between languages. Specifically, I've realized that `typedef`s won't translate to a lot of languages anyway. `%rename` works nicely with some example code I have for enums, but doesn't do anything with strings from what I've tested. I think my best option will be to either make `Message` into a full class or just document to use strings directly in the target language. The strong typedefs would probably be a good idea if I was heavily using typedefs rather than in just a few cases.

Comment: After some more thought on it, could you elaborate on using `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` with SWIG? Would it be possible to use `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` only in the SWIG bindings and regular `typedef`s or `using` aliases in the C++ code or would that likely cause issues?

Comment: That should be entirely possible. I'll work on an example later this weekend hopefully